# Функция, массивы, кнопка

Tags: javascript

Создал функцию, которая рисует таблицу и передал в неё массив. Количество столбцов и строк указываю в input, нажимаю кнопку и таблица рисуется, а когда меняю значение в input и снова нажимаю - появляется новая таблицы, но старая не удаляется. Как прописать в функцию удаление старой таблицы?

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');


  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = document.querySelector(".col1").value;
  var col = document.querySelector(".col2").value;
  var row_mas = [];
  var col_mas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var col_mas = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      col_mas.push(0);
    }
    row_mas.push(col_mas);
  }
  createTable(row_mas);


});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
th,
td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
}
tbody {
  background-color: blue;
}
input {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col1">
<input type="text" class="col2">
<button class="btn">Go</button>
```

Comment: Я немного правил ответ. Посмотрите улучшенный вариант с дополнением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для удаление DOM-элементов лучше всего использовать функцию [remove](https://learn.javascript.ru/task/remove-polyfill).

Мы сначала должны проверить, существует ли таблица. Если она сущетсвует, то мы удаляем все таблицы. Удаление можно сделать циклом или без него. Но я склоняюсь к созданию цикла, что бы удалить все таблицы, если она будет не одна.

И так же следует создаваемым таблицам прикреплять класс, что бы не удалялись другие (нужные) таблицы на странице:

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  // Проверяем на наличие таблицы
  if(document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length > 0){
    for(var i = document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      document.querySelectorAll('._Table')[i].remove(); // Удаляем таблицу
    };
  };
  
  table.classList.add('_Table');
  
  tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = document.querySelector(".col1").value;
  var col = document.querySelector(".col2").value;
  var row_mas = [];
  var col_mas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var col_mas = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      col_mas.push(0);
    }
    row_mas.push(col_mas);
  }
  createTable(row_mas);
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
th,
td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
}
tbody {
  background-color: blue;
}
input {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col1">
<input type="text" class="col2">
<button class="btn">Go</button>
```

Comment: стоит добавить описание чем именно приведенный код отличается от того, что в вопросе. В чем была проблема, и как именно она решилась

Comment: @Grundy, я в коде указал, что я добавил

Comment: лучше бы ты описал словами решение, у тебя очень плохой цикл удаления получился

Comment: @Grundy, почему плохой?

Comment: Потому что сработает, только если `document.querySelectorAll('table').length===1` при большем количестве при таком цикле будут дырки, то есть удалятся не все элементы

Comment: вообще при удалении элементов коллекции в цикле лучше идти с конца коллекции, это позволит избежать дырок, за счет того, что при сдвиге при удалении элементов индексы меняются только в уже просмотренной части

Comment: @Grundy, вы это имели введу? С задней части?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52051/discussion-between-grundy-and-yuri).

Comment: прос_ужс row_mas..

Comment: @OlmerDale, =D, я согласен, но тут следует заметить что название переменной наследовано из вопроса автора, видимо чтобы автор не задумывался лишний раз)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму да, не заметил, сорри за row_mass и _Ругаю за css класс  _Table.  _Ужас!

Comment: @OlmerDale, чем тебе класс не угодил?) Я все динамические классы, которые на долго не задержаться так называю

Comment: А если бы я называл вот так __лоыволаролв___лвораоврш6565546545_KLAC__ и делал такие примеры, Вы бы не подумали что я ненормальный?

Comment: @OlmerDale, 1) русские буквы не припустимы; 2) Название класса не несёт в себе никакой информации

Comment: А так? __KlacPaNe__l__PeDCOLOr_____ ?

Comment: @OlmerDale, ясно -_-